# What regex is \b equivalent to and is there a way to deparse it?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm interested in changing the regex word boundary `\b` to include other characters (for example, a `.` wouldn't count as a boundary). I understand that it is a boundary between `\w` and `\W` characters.

```
  my $_ = ".test";
  if ( /(\btest\b)/ ){
    print;
    print " $1\n";
  }
  if ( /((?:(?<=\W)|^)test(?:(?=\W)|$))/ ){
    print;
    print " $1\n";
  }
```

This is what I came up with, and all I'd have to do is change `\W` to something like `[^\w.]`, but I still want to know how Perl interprets `\b` in a regular expression. I tried deparsing it like this:

```
my $deparser = B::Deparse->new("-sC", "-x10");

print $deparser->coderef2text( sub { 
          my $_ = ".test";
          if ( /(\btest\b)/ ){
            print;
            print " $1\n";
          }
          if ( /((?:(?<=\W)|^)test(?:(?=\W)|$))/ ){
            print;
            print " $1\n";
          }
       });
```

I was hoping it would expand `\b` into what it was equivalent to. What is `\b` equivalent to? Can you deparse `\b` or other expressions further somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\b` is functionally equivalent to `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`.

`\B` is functionally equivalent to `(?<!\w)(?!\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\w)`.

---

The goal of Deparse is to produce a readable representation of Perl's understanding of the code. For example, `f() and g();` and `g() if f();` compile identically, so Deparse will give the more readable option, `g() if f();`, for both.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'f() and g()'
g() if f();
-e syntax OK
```

This means that if `\b` and `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)` compiled to the same code, Deparse would still give you `\b` if it understood compiled regex. Deparse is not what you want.

---

Maybe you're thinking of Concise. It shows what really gets executed. Notice the use of `and` in the following even though the original Perl uses `if`:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'g() if f()'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
5  <1> entersub[t6] sKS/TARG
6  <|> and(other->7) vK/1
7      <0> pushmark s
8      <#> gv[*g] s/EARLYCV
9      <1> entersub[t3] vKS/TARG
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

But like Deparse, Concise knows nothing of the regex program the regex engine created from the string. So this is still not what you want.

---

However, there is an equivalent of Concise for regex patterns: `use re 'debug';`.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -E'qr/\b/'
Compiling REx "\b"
Final program:
   1: BOUNDU (2)
   2: END (0)
stclass BOUNDU minlen 0
Freeing REx: "\b"
```

Apparently, `\b` is implemented as its own operation. For comparison,

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -E'qr/(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)/'
Compiling REx "(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)"
Final program:
   1: BRANCH (12)
   2:   UNLESSM[-1] (7)
   4:     POSIXU[\w] (5)
   5:     SUCCEED (0)
   6:   TAIL (7)
   7:   IFMATCH[0] (23)
   9:     POSIXU[\w] (10)
  10:     SUCCEED (0)
  11:   TAIL (23)
  12: BRANCH (FAIL)
  13:   IFMATCH[-1] (18)
  15:     POSIXU[\w] (16)
  16:     SUCCEED (0)
  17:   TAIL (18)
  18:   UNLESSM[0] (23)
  20:     POSIXU[\w] (21)
  21:     SUCCEED (0)
  22:   TAIL (23)
  23: END (0)
minlen 0
Freeing REx: "(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)"
```

Comment: +1. For further information, the non-word boundary `\B` is functionally equivalent to the logical negation of `\b`, that is, the logical negation of `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)` which -by applying De Morgan's law and simplifying- is equal to `(?<=\w)(?=\w)|(?<!\w)(?!\w)`.

Answer (score 7):

`\b` is the zero-width boundary between “a word character” (`\w`) and “not a word character” (which is something subtly different from “a non-word character” `\W`). So it would be equivalent to

```
(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

Deparsing will not work here because regexes are a *separate language* directly embedded into the Perl code. You can `use re 'debug'` to see how regexes are compiled and matched (see the [`re` docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/re) for more info on how to use this).

Comment: Even if Deparse was regex aware, it wouldn't do anything anyway since `\b` has its own regex opcode `perl -Mre=debug -E'qr/\b/'` vs `perl -Mre=debug -E'qr/(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)/'`